# How to create React SPA template with Visual Studio 2019 on Win

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I've installed preview 9 of asp.net core 3 on my windows machine and I want to create a new project with the React SPA templates that are part of core 3.

After installing the preview 9, I expected that I would be able to select core 3.0 in the dropdown of "Configure new project" and I would choose asp.net core 3, then I would see the new templates.  I just see asp.net core 2.2

What steps do I need to follow on windows to create the new preview 9 asp.net core 3 react template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.NET Core 3.0 should be used with the latest previews of Visual Studio**. Please check this and v3.0.0-preview9 supports Visual Studio 2019 (v16.3, latest preview).

Please, install a preview of VS 16.3 if you want to work with .NET Core 3.0.

Early Preview of the new VS Terminal. While the feature is disabled by default, you can enable it by going to **Tools** > **Options** > **Preview Features**.

You could refer to the following links :

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-9/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#whats-new-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: A little off topic, but is there a way to run this project, once created and working in VS2019, in VSCode? I installed the insiders version of code, opened the folder, debug/run no luck. tried installing c#, still no luck